# Convert Integer to String and Concatenate in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

Though question seems to be simple, I am trying to concatenate Integer and String by converting integer to string, My formula in DAX :

```
var storedata=450
var hours = QUOTIENT(storedata, 60)
var minutes = storedata - hours*60 

Return

FORMAT(hours,"")+":"+FORMAT(minutes,"")
```

Format function throws error **can't convert type string to type number**

But as per the documentation format function converts number to string but here error is totally opposite.

How can I convert Integer to String and concatenate.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function concatenate to return the result as a string:

```
Measure 4 = var storedata=450
var hours = QUOTIENT(storedata, 60)
var minutes = storedata - hours*60 

Return

CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(FORMAT(hours,""),":"),FORMAT(minutes,""))
```

This can solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. its working perfectly, can you please help me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: In my use case the problem as mainly because the ":". By this this I have the message "Cannot convert value ':' of type Text to type Number. So I replace your + signals to use the function concatenate 2 times to the double strings :)